# reading escape character as string from a file is not interpreted correctly in python

Tags: python, pyspark

I've a application.properties file, key-value pair depending on the condition I'm taking whether to consider single tab or double tab.
**application.properties:**

```
key1=\t
key2=\t\t
```

**main.py**

```
with open('application.properties', 'rt')
read and convert to key value pair
return props


str1 = 'abc    xyz'
str2 = 'def        jkl'
splitter1 = props['key1']
splitter2 = props['key2']
print(str1.split(splitter1)[1])
print(str1.split(splitter2)[1])
```

Indexerror: list of index out of range

```
print(type(splitter2) , splitter2)
```

<class 'str'> \t\t

Comment: `str1` does not appear to contain two tabs, so `str1.split('\t\t')` does not actually perform any splits, and thus index `[1]` is out of range.  (Did you intend the second split to be `str2` instead of `str1`?)

Answer (score 0):

Python processes `\t` in string *literals*, not string *values*. You'll have to replace the digraph `\t` with a tab character yourself. Something like

```
props = {}
with open('application.properties') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.strip().split('=')
        props[name] = value.replace(r'\t', '\t')
```

If there are other escape sequences that you expect to appear, you'll have to handle them yourself as well.